# How to reload a page and start a download by pressing the same link under Chrome? Works well under FF

Tags: java, google-chrome, jsf, primefaces

Basically I am trying to get 2 Responses from the server while sending only 1 Request. I have a table in Primefaces, where 1 column contains a p:commandLink, by pressing this link, the page is newly loaded, data updated and a download is started in a new Tab. (in FF life is great, it works without problem, but under Chrome the new Tab is stopped from being opened and I see one the requests being canceled).
The column with the problem contains the following:

```
<p:commandLink id="updateData" 
action="#bean.reloadPage()}"
onsuccess="document.getElementById("startDownload").onclick()">
    <f:param name="id" value="#{row.id}" />
</p:commandLink>



<p:commandLink id="startDownload"
ajax="false"
style="display: none"
action="#{bean.download()}"
target="_new" />
```

"Funny" is that under IE and FF is working..

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it had to do something with Chrome life cycle, while waiting for the "onsuccess" the original page that shot the request is already gone.. changing "onsuccess" to "onstart" had worked for me.